# Send array of objects without stringify as POST data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify

Is there a way to send array of objects without using JSON.stringify as POST data using Javascript?

```js
var loginData = [{
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: self.loginEmail(),
    password: self.loginPassword()
},{
    grant_type: 'password1',
    username: self.loginEmail1(),
    password: self.loginPassword1()
}];

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Token',
    data: loginData
}).done(function (data) {
    self.user(data.userName);
}).fail(showError);
```

Why do arrays of objects need to be stringified for requests when objects can just be sent as is?

Comment: You can send an array in the request. What error are you facing?

Comment: well documentation says `Type: PlainObject or String or Array
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string` so what error do you face?

Comment: @BalajKhan I was referring to array of objects.. not the array

Comment: I believe jquery will stringify it under the hood anyway.